# How can I avoid data redundancy?

Tags: database-design

One of the goals of good database design is to remove data redundancy (duplicate data). How can this be achieved during the design of the database?

Answer (score 1):

Normalization is moving a column (typically a string) from table, MAIN, to another table, NORM.  MAIN's column is replaced by an "id" (typically a small number) so that a `JOIN` to NORM allows for fetching the string.  NORM has [at least] the id and the string.

Let's discuss some of the uses and some of the pros and cons.

- When there are multiple tables (like MAIN) using that same "id", normalization allows you to centralize a name or attribute in a single place.  Then the application can change that one item in one place and automatically propagate it to all uses.
- Performance may improve or may degrade.  It depends on more details.
- Moving the same string out of multiple tables will [usually] save disk space and, hence, may improve performance
- On the other hand, to get the string, a `JOIN` is needed.
- Normalization *may* slow down queries on MAIN if the query needs to filter on the string that is now in NORM.  But, if there is only one such normalization table, the slowdown is probably insignificant.
- In general, do not Normalize a value that will be tested for a range (range of dates, numeric range, string wildcard, etc)  Performance is *likely* to suffer.
- A query that needs to filter on 2 normalized quantities, especially with range tests, is quite likely to run much slower than if the quantities were in MAIN.  (Simple Rule of Thumb:  Don't normalize anything numeric.)